# Data mismatch between a Source Server and a destination server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, openquery

I am trying to load data from a table in Oracle server to SQL server and data that gets loaded has mismathc rows. I am using Openquery to load the data. The data gets loaded perfectly fine in SQL Server 2013 but rows mismatch in SQL Server 2019. Anyone has ever come across this?

**Source Server data**

| State | City |
| --- | --- |
| NY | Syracuse |
| Florida | Orlando |
| Texas | Austin |

**Data loaded in destination server**

| State | City |
| --- | --- |
| NY | Austin |
| Florida | Syracuse |
| Texas | Orlando |

Below is the Openquery i am using

```
INSERT INTO table321
SELECT \* FROM OPENQUERY(hjgg, ''
select \*
FROM table1'')
```

Comment: @Dale K i don't think that's the issue I would expect NY/SYRACUSE to port as NY/SYRACUSE but it has ported as NY/AUSTIN . I wouldn't necessarily expect row order to be maintained though.

Comment: Are you using exactly the same version of the Oracle ODBC driver as you were on the older server? It's not unheard of for [specific](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1297281_1.html) [versions](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2035249_1.html) of Oracle ODBC drivers to have corruption issues.

Comment: 2 things , Insert and select, to help debug run select in isolation, what does it produce?(in both sql-server versions)

Comment: You say it's fine in sql-server 2013 but not 2019 but you don't mention oracle version(s) or whether you upgraded all drivers when you moved to sql-server 2019

Comment: And I would specify target and source columns rather using default on insert and * on select.